# Change firefox bookmarks toolbar tooltips

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, toolbar

Does anyone know if it is possible to control what FireFox puts in the tool-tip windows that are displayed when hovering the pointer over the icons in the bookmarks toolbar?  The default content seems to be a combination of the 'Name' and 'Location' fields from the properties dialog for the bookmark.

Ideally, I'd like to make it not display the 'Location' part in the tool-tip, and possibly not even the 'Name', but would really like it to show the properties 'Description'.

The motivation behind this is that I save screen real-estate by clearing the 'Name' field; this eliminates the text that appears to the right of the icons, so I can jam dozens of the things in. The tool-tips help identify an icon when I forget what it stands for, but with Name erased, that leaves only the Location, and those aren't always as obvious as http://superuser.com is.  And usually, to preserve the information, when I clear out the Name field, I just paste it into the Description field.  Hence the desire to make the tool-tip show the Description text.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about screen real estate, you might look into the [Smart Bookmarks Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4072) Firefox extension.

> Smart Bookmarks Bar modifies the bookmarks bar to show bookmarks icons only.
>
> Bookmark names will be displayed on mouse over. This feature can be disactivated if you just want icons without the rollover effect.

[image: Smart Bookmarks Bar Screenshot]

Comment: you're probably better off with smart bookmarks than coding it all over again.

Comment: From addon page: Note from Mozilla: This add-on has been discontinued. Try Roomy Bookmarks Toolbar instead.

Comment: Roomy Bookmarks Toolbar is unfortunately also discontinued. For more information and a solution to this problem, see here: https://superuser.com/a/39635/439537

Answer (score 2):

This Firefox add-on may be of interest: [Places' Tooltips](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/places-tooltips/)

> This addon enhances all the tooltips in Firefox.
>
> Shows a tooltip for all links, folders, bookmarks and RSS items on
>   Bookmarks Toolbar, Bookmarks Menu', History Menu' and also Sidebars!
>
> You can also see the last visited date, tags, description and the
>   keywords!

For what it's worth, there used to be a related bug report on [Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256065) since 2004, which was closed as RESOLVED WONTFIX in 2013.